# Update ImageMagick Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

I would like to update my version of ImageMagick.  I originally installed ImageMagick with...

```
sudo apt-get imagemagick
```

Current Version:

```
myapp$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Location:

```
myapp$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

System:  Ubuntu14.04 / Apache2.47 / Passenger 4.0.5.5 / Rails 4.1.1 / Ruby 2.1.5

I do not have brew installed.  What is the advised way to update?

Comment: I think Ask Ubuntu would fit even better as a place for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to install the latest version from the Ubuntu sources, use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick
```

But it seems that your version is already the current one for Ubuntu 14.04. Upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version would also lead to a newer imagemagick package, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/imagemagick

Alternatively, you can try a version that has been built for a later Ubuntu release, see e.g. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/imagemagick. Download the deb-file suited for your machine architecture, and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
apt-get install -f
```

However, it is not guaranteed by the Ubuntu developers that this mixing of packages for different Ubuntu versions will work well. But since this is only a single package, there is a good chance that it will work well.

Finally, you can also build it from the upstream sources, see

https://askubuntu.com/questions/267746/how-can-i-install-the-latest-upstream-version-of-imagemagick-without-compiling